# Remove Theme.AppCompact Dependency for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and for that i had to add `Theme.AppCompact` to the activity in my manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="ActicityName"
            android:label="ActivityLabel"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        </activity>
```

that is overriding my button layou, how can i remove this `AppCompact` dependency.

EDIT

for example in my `layout` i have a button like

```
<Button           
            android:background="@drawable/bg_state"           
            android:textColor="@color/btn_textstate"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

According to developer.android.com, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html, you need to use some AppCompat theme, 
but they also say " If you've created a custom theme, be sure it uses one of the Theme.AppCompat themes as its parent. "

So if you have a custom theme, you can set some Theme.AppCompat as it's parent and then use it as before.

Or you can create button style or find which one of android button styles you need, and add it in xml to your Button, eg style="?attr/actionButtonStyle";

Comment: i have not made my own theme rather created styles for buttons so they can change color on state (enable/disable) change. How can i add that to my custom theme?

Comment: what is the theme you used in your activity or application before you changed it to Theme.AppCompat? I think you could add default button style from that theme to your button

Comment: well i as not using any theme, i didnt specified the `android:theme` in any activity in manifest

Comment: perhaps it was specified during project creation, you can check in styles.xml. Perhaps you can try with style="@android:style/Widget.Button". If it doesn't work, then tell what is the difference between appearances before and after applying AppCompat